Unable to play animation from another layer

I'm attempting to play an animation from different layers but having some difficulty. I'm trying to play animation transitions in one layer and then go back to the base layer to play an animation after the transition is completed. However, the animation in the base layer isn't playing. Here's a sample of the code:
 private IEnumerator MyFunc1(Animator animator)
{
  animator.enabled = true;
  animator.SetLayerWeight(7, 1f);
  animator.SetBool("isJumpingFromSitting", true);

}

StartCoroutine(MyFunc1(Player_animator);


m_Player1.GetComponent<Animator>().enabled = true;
m_Player1.GetComponent<Animator>().SetLayerWeight(0, 1f);
m_Player1.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("Clapping");


Help is appreciated.

Also, we're unable to play the same transitions, consecutively. That is, after the 1st call to animation transition in another layer, all subsequent calls will not play. It appears that the maybe the parameters are resetting or there maybe some interference with the layer? Could this be related to initial issue or question in this post?

We were able to resolve the issue of not being able to play animations from different layers by syncing the animation transition or layers w/ the Base Layer. However, the animation transitions now play too fast. We’ve tried slowing down the speed of the animation clips in each transition but to no avail. Also, tried Addictive Blending, so that the speed settings would not be overridden and that didn’t work, either.
Help is appreciated.
